# Combinatorics: Why/how does this solution for counting three digit numbers work?

Tags: combinatorics

My homework book lists three different solutions for the exercise below, I used the most obvious one, (counting all possible configurations with one 2 and two 2's), but the book also gives this other (much shorter) solution. Sadly I do not understand what they are doing or why it works. Concretely I would like to know what they mean with: "the number of 3 digits numbers with all digits at least 2/3".

**Exercise:**
What is the probability that a random number of 3 (possibly identical) digits has a 2 as the
lowest digit? Note that `N(S) = 1000` because numbers like `000` and `010` count too.

**Shortest solution:**
Consider the number of 3 digits numbers with all digits at least 2 (includes for example 
`367`) and cancel all numbers with digits at least 3: `8^3 − 7^2 = 169`. Thus: `P(A) = 169/1000 = 16.9%`.

Comment: There are $8^3$ three digit strings made from the eight digits $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  There are $7^3$ three digit strings made from the seven digits $3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  There are therefore $8^3-7^3=169$ three digit strings made from the eight digits $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ which include at least one $2$.

Comment: $8^3$ is the number of three digit numbers where all digits come from $\{2,3,4,\dots,9\}$ with no further restriction.  Included in this are examples like $222, 257, 354, 392, 997$ and many more.  $7^3$ is the number of three digit numbers where all digits come from $\{3,4,5,\dots,9\}$ and includes numbers like $354, 997$ and more.  Notice that each of these was also included in the previous count but this notably does not contain any number which contains a $2$ that was counted before like $222, 257$ etc...

Comment: The $7^2$ in the quoted solution is a typo; it should be $7^3$ (as in both of the preceding comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is you are taking the set of all strings with digits at least $2$, which is a prerequisite, and removing the subset that doesn't contain any $2$'s. You need at least one $2$ to be in the desired set, and need digits to be at least $2$. So you take the ones with all digits at least $2$ and remove the ones that don't have a $2$ in them.